# access to new branch from terminal which is created on gitlab

Tags: git

I created a new branch called mybranch from master using gitlab UI. There are 10 other branches from other people. In the terminal when I write: `git branch`
It shows me I am in the master branch and no other branch is shown.
when I put: `git switch mybranch`
or: `git checkout mybranch`
it gives error such as invalid reference
how I can go into mybranch from terminal? I can see the branch in the gitlab page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created the branch on remote repository and you're trying to access it on your local clone of the repository.

To be able to do so you need to `fetch` the refs available in the remote repository. You could do this with:

```
git fetch origin
```

Afterwards you could verify that the new branches are available locally by executing:

```
git branch --all
```

Seeing that the branch you're looking for is there you could check it out using:

```
git checkout mybranch
```

Comment: there is switch command! I switch between branches using it

Comment: @Saba TIL about git's 2.23 git restore and git switch, thanks! :) https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.23.0.txt#L61